# How to check Dynamic URI in laravel Blade file

Tags: laravel, url, request, uri

I am using laravel 7 and need to check Request::path() where Url will have dynamic values
Route in
web.php

```
 Route::get('/user/portfolio/{id}/{cid}', 'UserController@portoView')->name('user_portfolio_view');
```

URL on browser
http://cat-and-pillar.ets/user/portfolio/34/1

where 34 and 1 always dynamic. i need to add some condition on all these type of URl

Thank you in advance

Comment: Those values are `dynamic`, that's the point of route parameters. Can you provide further explination as to what you're attempting to do?

Comment: @Peppermintology i was adding class on div by identifying the route using this inline condition <div class="annoucement {{ Request::path() == 'trademark' || Request::path() == 'renew' || Request::path() == 'postassessment' ? 'hideannoucment' : '' }}"> just need to one more condition for this dynamic route.

Comment: Can you provide an example URL that contains the term(s) you are wanting to match?

Comment: @Peppermintology http://cat-and-pillar.ets/user/portfolio/34/1

Comment: Nowhere in that example is the term `trademark` or `renew`. You need to provide an example where it could contain one of your terms for people to provide an accurate solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all route params using

```
$request->route()->parameters()
```

This will output

```
array:2 [▼
  "id" => "34"
  "cid" => "1"
]
```

To get url segement ,you can use

```
request()->segment(1)  //user
request()->segment(2)  //portfolio
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I am adding inline condition using Request::path()
i just need to identify there is a route like above in the blade file, we don't need to know what values are sorry o forget to the mentioned blade file in above question.

Comment: then try  $request->route()->parameterNames. it give params if you need url $request->route()->uri

Comment: even you can check if count of $request->route()->parameters() greater than 0 then its has params

Comment: thank you but I need to do this in the blade file.

Comment: @Jonh Basically i am already adding some class by identifying the route using this inline condition <div class="annoucement {{ Request::path() == 'trademark' || Request::path() == 'renew' || Request::path() == 'postassessment' ? 'hideannoucment' : '' }}">

just need to one more condition for this dynamic route.

Comment: @VinayKaithwas.can you mention one condition which matches in question route. request path return you user/portfolio/34/1 this so if you want to compare user/portpolio then use request segement